# can not show messages received in console with pusher and websocket

Tags: laravel, websocket

for project i used pusher to create realtime chat using laravel 9 . i can send message from front end to backend with api but can not received messages from backend

chat channel created but won't show up anything

for example when an event called backend completely received that but could not send anything or can not connect to channel

js :

```
Echo.channel('chat').listen('.MyMessage', (e) => {
    console.log(e)
})
```

could anyone help me ?

Comment: I had same issue, then I just downgrade the stoped pusher server to 7.0.2 by using composer command like `composer require pusher/pusher-php-server:7.0.2` the new versions of pusher server have event issue

Comment: @Nazari i realized that its about a bug which can not read correct cluster from env file which completely confused me ;) use the default mt1 it will be okey